# Unable to "stake_and_deposit" more than 24 N via custom function call form on Sputnik v2

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to delegate NEAR to a validator inside the V2 Sputnik DAO using **deposit_and_stake** custom function call on the DAO (simplegames.sputnik-dao.near). I managed to get it to work, but it does not listen to the arguments of:

```
{
  "amount": "10000000000000000000000000" // 10 N
}
```

It only allows to take the **proposal deposit** for **deposit_and_stake**, rather than use funds inside the DAO.

If I try to fill out the form for a custom function call, it blocks me trying to use any deposit for a proposal to do this with requiring a maximum of 24 N. This is a blocker to use **deposit_and_stake** functionality inside a DAO via the custom form.

Would be great to have suggestions or how to fix this?

Edit: This is the call I tried manually from command line, but I get

"This proposal is created with an incorrect data, please consider removing and creating a new one".

```
near call chaintyping-test2.sputnikv2.testnet add_proposal '{"proposal": {"description": "5 N deposit_and_stake", "submission_time": "60000000000", "kind": {"FunctionCall": { "receiver_id": "staked.pool.f863973.m0", "actions":[{ "method_name": "deposit_and_stake", "args":"", "deposit":"5000000000000000000000000", "gas": "75000000000000"}]}}}}' --accountId mic.testnet --amount 5
```

Comment: This might be a UI limitation. Have you tried via REPL/command line, as demonstrated by this write up? https://hackmd.io/lMmmRVXASuGf9Xrx75Pmlw

Comment: Can you provide the full json you used to create a custom call?

Comment: I just updated this post with a command line call I've been trying to use. Thank you!